# Changing the font size and placement of selected feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, mac, font

I have downloaded map data as an FGDB folder. There are names of places where some of them need to be highlighted and also moved a little. Names of places.

I select a placename (feature) and try "edit"-"edit attributes"-"modify attributes of selected features". This menu point is dimmed out and not available.

Maybe selected features can't be edited?

If I open the layer properties and change the text size in Labels. It works. But not on selected features. Only everyone.

The toggle edit is grey. Maybe a sign of a problem.

If I open the attribute table as a selected feature. The content of the form is not editable.

If I copy the feature as a temporary scratch layer and then a GeoJSON. It's saved. But then I can't hide the feature it's on top of residing on the other layer.

The folders these files are inside are set to read and write for my user. And also as read/write for "everyone".

I am using MacOS Ventura 13.2 QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze QGIS code revision b47e00ba60
[image]

Comment: Please provide the current label settings.

Comment: Is 3.28.2 on the Mac built against the new editable FGDB driver?

Comment: Erik: I guess you mean the Label settings for text as the font site is in the text section. Tell me if there is another section of the label settings you would like to look at. Thanks for getting into this.

Llaves: Hm not shure I can give an answear on this. Maybe an external driver is needed?

Comment: @ErlandFlaten - prior to 3.28, the FGDB driver did not support editing layers. I was hoping someone who was familiar with the Mac build could answer the question

Comment: Ah. I understand. I have been reading around. Hope the driver can write back to the files. I have also found out then map files are available as PostGIS, so maybe thats a better way.

Comment: For label's properties only you can use Label Toolbar instruments. This way your changes will be saved in local auxiliary storage, not original FileGDB.

Comment: @RainForest I have made an copy of the feature and changed size colour, offset placement and more,  and that works. The problem is the feature i copied from is still on the map and should be turned off. Which I guess is not possible. But maybe I missunderstand what you mean by Lable Toolbar Instruments? can clear out that for me, please?

Comment: Update and thanks.  I can use the label toolbars, as you suggested over, exept the rightmost one called "change label properties". It gives the error message. Cannot change namoflabel because layer cant be made editable.